# RF-4.5.x How to get PickList selected Items in backing bean

Tags: richfaces, picklist

I have a PickList and I want to take the selected items from the component and persist in DB. But I am not sure on how to get the selected values in my backing bean class. below is my code. Is there any method to get the target values from PickList.

```
<rich:pickList id="userListShuttle"
       binding="#{sampleBean.pickLst}"
       var="roles"
       value="#{sampleBean.newRoles}"
       sourceCaption="Available Roles"
       targetCaption="Assigned Roles"
       listWidth="440px" listHeight="145px"
       orderControlsVisible="false"
       fastOrderControlsVisible="false">
       <f:selectItems value="#{sampleBean.availableRoles}"/>
</rich:pickList>
```

### Java Code:

```
@Component( "sampleBean" )
@Scope( "request" )
public class SampleBean {

    private List<String> newRoles;   
    private List<String> availableRoles;   
    private UIPickList pickLst = new UIPickList();

     /**
     * @return the newRoles
     */
    public List<String> getNewRoles() {
        newRoles = new ArrayList<String>();       
        newRoles.add( "Role 3" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 4" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 5" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 6" );
        Collections.sort( newRoles );
        return newRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @param newRoles the newRoles to set
     */
    public void setNewRoles( List<String> newRoles ) {
        this.newRoles = newRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @return the availableRoles
     */
    public List<String> getAvailableRoles() {
        availableRoles = new ArrayList<String>();
        availableRoles.add( "Role 1" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 2" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 3" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 4" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 5" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 6" );
        Collections.sort( availableRoles );
        return availableRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @param availableRoles the availableRoles to set
     */
    public void setAvailableRoles( List<String> availableRoles ) {
        this.availableRoles = availableRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @return the roleShuttle
     */
    public UIPickList getPickLst() {
        return roleShuttle;
    }

    /**
     * @param roleShuttle the roleShuttle to set
     */
    public void setPickLst( UIPickList pickLst) {
        this.pickLst= pickLst;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little changes, and this is the result:

**JSF Code:**

```
   <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid>
                <rich:panel >
                <rich:pickList id="userListShuttle"
                        switchByClick="true"
                        value="#{testClass.newRoles}"
                        sourceCaption="Available Roles"
                        targetCaption="Assigned Roles"
                        listWidth="440px" listHeight="145px"                      
                        valueChangeListener="#{testClass.onSelectListItem}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" render=" " />  
                    <f:selectItems value="#{testClass.availableRoles}" var="label"/>
                 </rich:pickList>
                </rich:panel >
            </h:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
```

**Java Bean:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TestClass {
     private List<String> newRoles;   
    private List<String> availableRoles;   

    public List<String> getNewRoles() {
        newRoles = new ArrayList<String>();       
        newRoles.add( "Role 3" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 4" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 5" );
        newRoles.add( "Role 6" );
        Collections.sort( newRoles );
        return newRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @param newRoles the newRoles to set
     */
    public void setNewRoles( List<String> newRoles ) {
        this.newRoles = newRoles;
    }

    /**
     * @return the availableRoles
     */
    public List<String> getAvailableRoles() {
        availableRoles = new ArrayList<String>();
        availableRoles.add( "Role 1" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 2" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 3" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 4" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 5" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 6" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 7" );
        availableRoles.add( "Role 8" );
        Collections.sort( availableRoles );
        return availableRoles;
    }


    public void setAvailableRoles( List<String> availableRoles ) {
        this.availableRoles = availableRoles;
    }

    public void onSelectListItem(ValueChangeEvent event){
        System.err.println("___________________");
       List <String> items = (List<String>)event.getNewValue();
       for (String item : items){
           System.err.println("Rol:" + item);
       }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: output image]

Answer (score 0):

@value is the right attribute, though I am not sure how you expect your example to work if you overwrite the `newRoles` every time the getter is called (do not put business logic into getters/setters). You do not need to access the instance of UIPickList, the selected values will be saved to `newRoles`, you get it directly from the bean.

Comment: Thank you for you response. It is working.. So, I have moved all the logic to my constructor and I am able to get the changed values from 'newRoles' in my backing bean..  once again thank you for your response..